# How to setup routing for a downgraded Angular 6 application in to an AngularJS application?

Tags: angularjs, angular, routes, ng-upgrade

I've got a large AngularJS application with a downgraded Angular 6 application inside of it. If I navigate directly to the Angular application then it loads properly. If I navigate to the AngularJS home page and then go to the Angular 6 url then the component does not load. Also, once the Angular 6 component loads it appears on every page within the app.

My setup is not quite there. I actually can't find any guides for setting up routing in this particular scenario (they all seem to be for upgraded AngularJS routing).

I'm sorry I can't get a working example - it's a complicated setup.

**Angular 6**

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule, Inject, ErrorHandler, ApplicationRef } from "@angular/core";
import { AngularFireModule } from "@angular/fire";
import { RouterModule, UrlHandlingStrategy } from "@angular/router";
import { HttpClientModule } from "@angular/common/http";
import { AngularFirestoreModule } from "@angular/fire/firestore";
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { UpgradeModule, downgradeComponent } from "@angular/upgrade/static";
import { NgbModule } from "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap";
import { CoreModule } from "../core/core.module";
import { WorkHelpModule } from "../work-help/work-help.module";
import { APP_CONFIG, AppConfig } from "./app.config";

import * as angular from "angular";
import moduleName from "../../app/scripts/app/app.module";
import { AirbrakeErrorHandler } from "../ErrorHandler";
import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";
import { StoreModule } from "@ngrx/store";
import { EffectsModule } from "@ngrx/effects";
import { reducers } from "../app/store";

export class Ng1Ng2UrlHandlingStrategy implements UrlHandlingStrategy {
  shouldProcessUrl(url) {
    console.log(
      "shouldProcessUrl",
      url.toString().startsWith("/work-help")
    );
    return url.toString().startsWith("/work-help");
  }
  extract(url) {
    return url;
  }
  //@ts-ignore
  merge(url, whole) {
    return url;
  }
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    UpgradeModule,
    NgbModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([]),
    StoreModule.forRoot(reducers, {}),
    EffectsModule.forRoot([]),
    CoreModule,
    WorkHelpModule,
    AngularFirestoreModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp({ // deleted }),
  ],
  entryComponents: [AppComponent],
  providers: [
    { provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: AirbrakeErrorHandler },
    { provide: APP_CONFIG, useValue: AppConfig },
    { provide: UrlHandlingStrategy, useClass: Ng1Ng2UrlHandlingStrategy },
  ],
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor(
    private upgrade: UpgradeModule,
    @Inject(APP_CONFIG) private config
  ) {}

  ngDoBootstrap(app: ApplicationRef) {
    angular
      .module("config", [])
      .constant("settings", this.config)
      .constant("appName", "student");

    angular.injector(["ng", "config"]).invoke([
      "$http",
      $http =>
        $http({
          method: "GET",
          url: `${this.config.ENV.apiHost}/api/v2/roles`,
          headers: { Accept: "application/vnd.api+json" },
        })
          .then(response => {
            angular.module("config").constant("allRoles", response.data);
            this.upgrade.bootstrap(document.documentElement, [moduleName], {
              strictDi: true,
            });
            app.bootstrap(AppComponent);
          })
          .catch((/**response */) => {
            // console.log(response); // uncomment if bootstrapping is failing
            angular
              .element("body")
              .html(
                `<h1 class="text-center color-red">We're sorry. There's been an error.</h1>`
              );
          }),
    ]);
  }
}

angular
  .module(moduleName)
  .directive("appComponent", downgradeComponent({ component: AppComponent }));
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "app-component",
  template: `
    <div id="app-component">
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor() {}
}
```

**AngularJS**

app.routes.js

```
export function appRoutes(
  $stateProvider,
  $urlRouterProvider,
  $locationProvider
) {
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
  $stateProvider
    .state("student", {
      abstract: true,
      component: "app",
      data: {
        permissions: {
          only: "hasValidSession",
          redirectTo: "login",
        },
      },
      resolve: {
        student: ["Student", Student => Student.ready],
        setPassword: [
          "Student",
          "student",
          (Student, student) => {
            if (!student.requireSetPassword || !!Student.spoofer) {
              return true;
            }
            return Student.openSetPasswordModal();
          },
        ],
      },
      redirectTo: "student.home",
    })
    .state("student.home", {
      url: "/",
      component: "home",
      data: { pageTitle: "Home" },
    });
}

appRoutes.$inject = [
  "$stateProvider",
  "$urlRouterProvider",
  "$locationProvider",
];
```

index.html (excerpt)

```
   <ui-view></ui-view>
   <app-component></app-component>
```

work-help.routes.js

```
export function workHelpRoutes($stateProvider) {
  $stateProvider
    .state("student.workHelpOld", {
      url: "/work-help-old",
      component: "WorkHelp",
      data: { pageTitle: "Work Help" },
      resolve: {
        student: ["student", student => student],
        enrollment: [
          "EnrollmentService",
          EnrollmentService =>
            EnrollmentService.get({
              active: true,
              include: "brand,course",
              brandName: "Work Help",
            }).$promise.then(response => response.enrollments.first()),
        ],
      },
    })
    .state("student.workHelp", {
      url: "/work-help",
      data: { pageTitle: "Work Help" },
      resolve: {},
    });
}

workHelpRoutes.$inject = ["$stateProvider"];
```